# Optimal Approach for Iterating and Processing Large CSV Files with Calculations in Python

Tags: python, csv, memory-management, large-files, data-processing

Is there an efficient way to iterate through a large CSV file in Python, performing calculations on specific columns and storing the results in a new file?

I attempted to process a substantial CSV file using Python's built-in CSV module, where I iterated through rows and performed calculations on specific columns. I expected the processing to be efficient and the calculated results to be stored accurately in a new file.

However, as the file size increased, the processing time became noticeably slower. Additionally, I encountered memory errors when trying to load the entire file into memory for calculations. This resulted in delays and potential crashes during the processing.

I'm now seeking guidance on more efficient methods or libraries to handle large CSV files and perform calculations on specific columns while minimizing memory usage and optimizing processing speed.

Comment: The csv module is really quite trivial and likely to be very efficient. There's almost certainly an error in your code (which you have chosen not to share)